Application crash with _isPlatformVersionAtLeast SIGABRT (ABORT) - APMIdentityWorkerQueue
I am working on a cross-platform application, and we recently released updates for our apps. We received a large number of crashes in our Crashlytics logs. All the crashes seem to occur in the APM submodule classes with "__isPlatformVersionAtLeast SIGABRT (ABORT)." While checking the Crashlytics event summary details, I found that the crashes happen during the execution of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the AppDelegate.
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    //Firebase 
    [FIRPerformance sharedInstance].instrumentationEnabled = 0; 
    [FIRApp configure]; 
    NSDictionary *props = @{ @"TESTING": @"iOS", @"Date": [NSDate date] }; 
    //Clevertap
    [[CleverTap sharedInstance] setInAppNotificationDelegate:self];
    [[CleverTap sharedInstance] setPushNotificationDelegate:self];
    NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
    NSLog(@"appPath ------ %@",appPath); 
    // Config an additional instance 
    NSLog(@"multiple instance registration"); 
    CleverTapInstanceConfig *ctConfig = [[CleverTapInstanceConfig alloc]     initWithAccountId:@"TEST*******" accountToken:@"TEST*****"]; 
    NSLog(@"multiple instance registration %@",ctConfig);
    CleverTap *additionalCleverTapInstance = [CleverTap instanceWithConfig:ctConfig];
    [AEPMobileCore setLogLevel:AEPLogLevelDebug];
    [AEPMobileCore configureWithAppId:@"99********"]; 
    return YES;
}

Podfile:
pod 'Firebase/Analytics' 
pod 'Firebase/Auth' 
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '10.28.1' 
pod 'FirebasePerformance', '10.28.0' 
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig' 
pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK', '6.2.1' 

Stack Trace:
Crashed: APMIdentityWorkerQueue 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib          0xc274 __pthread_kill + 8 
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x7ef8 pthread_kill + 268
2 libsystem_c.dylib               0x77ad8 abort + 128 
3 libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x9c38 malloc_vreport + 896 
4 libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x98a8 malloc_report + 64 
5 libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x8e80 find_zone_and_free + 528 
6 App 0xfe574                     (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
7 App 0xf7e04                     (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
8 App 0xfc250                     (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
9 App 0xfbbec                     (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
10 App 0x2b4d00                   (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
11 App 0x2bed74                   (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
12 App 0x18344c                   (Missing UUID 0faca6be3dbe3121a960c0897cece480) 
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7ef8 pthread_kill + 268 
14 App 0x28354fc                  __isPlatformVersionAtLeast + 4384462076 
15 ??? 0x3015b5920                (Missing) 
16 ??? 0xd5e00078c                (Missing) 
17 ??? 0x1f058ed                  (Missing)

APMExperimentWorkerQueue
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x815f0 sqlite3_table_column_metadata + 2400
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x13b2c sqlite3_exec + 46032
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0xaae0 sqlite3_exec + 9092
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x9ac8 sqlite3_exec + 4972
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x9158 sqlite3_exec + 2556
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x12830 sqlite3_exec + 41172
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x11f20 sqlite3_exec + 38852
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x11e64 sqlite3_exec + 38664
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0xb14bc sqlite3_sourceid + 132108
9  libsqlite3.dylib               0xd130 sqlite3_exec + 18900
10 libsqlite3.dylib               0xc224 sqlite3_exec + 15048
11 libsqlite3.dylib               0x9ac8 sqlite3_exec + 4972
12 libsqlite3.dylib               0x9158 sqlite3_exec + 2556
13 libsqlite3.dylib               0x8d30 sqlite3_exec + 1492
14 App                            0x58249c -[APMSqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] + 4339819676
15 App                            0x58295c -[APMSqliteStore validateDatabaseWithError:] + 4339820892
16 App                            0x58289c -[APMSqliteStore openAndValidateDatabase:] + 4339820700
17 App                            0x57ecbc -[APMSqliteStore initWithDatabasePath:error:] + 4339805372
18 App                            0x505ae4 -[APMEDatabase initializeDatabaseResourcesWithContext:databasePath:] + 4339309284
19 App                            0x505a0c -[APMEDatabase initWithPath:] + 4339309068
20 App                            0x50d294 -[APMETaskManager startTaskManagerOnWorkerQueue] + 4339339924
21 App                            0x50d24c __35-[APMETaskManager startTaskManager]_block_invoke + 4339339852
22 App                            0x50e578 __46-[APMETaskManager dispatchAsyncOnWorkerQueue:]_block_invoke + 4339344760
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x213c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
25 libdispatch.dylib              0xb400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
26 libdispatch.dylib              0xbf30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x16cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x16528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4934 _pthread_wqthread + 288
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

Podfile.lock
- Firebase/Analytics (10.28.1):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Auth (10.28.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 10.28.0)
  - Firebase/Core (10.28.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 10.28.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (10.28.1):
    - FirebaseCore (= 10.28.1)
  - Firebase/Crashlytics (10.28.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 10.28.1)
  - FirebaseABTesting (10.29.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (10.28.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 10.28.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (10.28.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 10.28.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.29.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (10.28.0):
    - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (~> 10.17)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)
    - RecaptchaInterop (~> 100.0)
  - FirebaseCore (10.28.1):
    - FirebaseCoreInternal (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.12)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.12)
  - FirebaseCoreExtension (10.29.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseCoreInternal (10.29.0):
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (10.28.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.5)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop (~> 10.23)
    - FirebaseSessions (~> 10.5)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseInstallations (10.29.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.8)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
  - FirebasePerformance (10.28.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.5)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseRemoteConfig (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseSessions (~> 10.5)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.13)
    - GoogleUtilities/ISASwizzler (~> 7.13)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.13)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.13)
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseRemoteConfig (10.29.0):
    - FirebaseABTesting (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop (~> 10.23)
    - FirebaseSharedSwift (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
  - FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop (10.29.0)
  - FirebaseSessions (10.29.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.5)
    - FirebaseCoreExtension (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.13)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.13)
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesSwift (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseSharedSwift (10.29.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (10.28.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (= 10.28.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (10.28.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (= 10.28.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (10.28.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (9.4.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (< 2.30911.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (6.0.0):
    - GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore
    - MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 5.0.0)
  - GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (6.0.0):
    - MLKitCommon (~> 11.0.0)
  - GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition (6.0.0):
    - GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore
    - MLKitTextRecognition (~> 4.0.0)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (4.2.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (4.2.1):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 4.2.1)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (4.2.1)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 4.2.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/ISASwizzler (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.13.3)":
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilities/Privacy (7.13.3)
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.13.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Privacy
  - GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (3.5.0)
  - nanopb (2.30910.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30910.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30910.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30910.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30910.0)
  - PromisesObjC (2.4.0)
  - PromisesSwift (2.4.0):
    - PromisesObjC (= 2.4.0)

Deployment version: 12.2 & 13.0
Could anyone know the above issue?

What are the versions in Podfile.lock?

@PaulBeusterien Podfile.lock details updated in the question. Kindly check and update

Thanks. Nothing looks problematic to me. Sorry.
